# erase in canvas not working. Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, erase

I created an application where i used canvas and pencil tool etc. What i need now is an erase tool, which clears the previous lines. I tried the erase that uses background color as the pencil. I don't need that one. I implemented the `PorterDuff.Mode`, but somehow it is not working, so please help me.

```
public void colorChanged22() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     canvasPathPaint.setXfermode(null);

    canvasPathPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
     canvasPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
     canvasPathPaint.setDither(true);
    canvasPathPaint.setAlpha(0);

    canvasPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvasPathPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    canvasPathPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPathPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    canvasPathPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));


    drawingBitmap = drawingBitmap.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);

}
```

I used this method for eraser button in the application. But it does not work. It does not clear the previous lines drawn.

EDITED
FULL CODE
This is not full code, as i cant disclose my code.I posted some part of it to explain in detail.

```
PaintRunner.java

private final Xfermode eraseXfermode;
private final Canvas bitmapCanvas;
private final Paint bitmapPathPaint;
private final Paint canvasPathPaint;



public PaintRunner(PaintView paintView, Context context) {

surfaceHolder = paintView.getHolder();
    commandManager = new CommandManager(context);
    mContext = context;

    super.setRunnable(new DrawLoop());
bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();

bitmapPathPaint = new Paint();
    bitmapPathPaint.setColor(color);
    bitmapPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    bitmapPathPaint.setDither(true);
    bitmapPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    bitmapPathPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    bitmapPathPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    bitmapPathPaint.setStrokeWidth(appContext.maxStrokeWidth() / 9);

    canvasPathPaint = new Paint(bitmapPathPaint);

    Bitmap checkerboard = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(appContext.getResources(), R.drawable.black);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = (context).getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    checkerboard = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(checkerboard, screenWidth, screenHeight, true);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(checkerboard, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    checkeredPattern = new Paint();
    checkeredPattern.setShader(shader);

    // eraseXfermode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    eraseXfermode = new Xfermode();
```

this is the eraser method which is called when eraser button is clicked

```
canvasPathPaint.setXfermode(null);
    canvasPathPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
    canvasPathPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    canvasPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvasPathPaint.setDither(true);
    canvasPathPaint.setAlpha(0);
    System.out.println("color " + color);
    canvasPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvasPathPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    canvasPathPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPathPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    canvasPathPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    // drawingBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    drawingBitmap = drawingBitmap.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Comment: canvasPathPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)); is used to erase the draw on touch and move. this should work can you post your full code?